# Difference of two List with different types using LINQ

Tags: linq

I am trying the get the different of two lists with a LINQ query. But  the lists are not of the same type.

```
List<Vehicle> unsoldVehicles
List<string> ListDetailUrls
```

Each Vehicle Object has a field called *UrlID* (string) while the *ListDetailUrls* list consists only of strings. 
I need every Vehicle from the Vehicle List where the field *UrlID* does not match an entry *ListDetailUrls*.

What I have done so far is :

```
List<Vehicle> missingVehicles = new List<Vehicle>(
    from uV in unsoldVehicles
    from de in ListDetailUrls
    where uV.UrlID != de
    select uV);
```

But with a query like this my *missingVehicles* are more items than the *unsoldVehicles*!

I was looking for a way to use the Except-method somehow but I only find samples where both lists are of the same type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
var missingvehicles = from uV in unsoldVehicles
                    where !listDetailUrls.Contains(uV.UrlID )
                    select uV;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your current query is incorrect is because **all** combinations of `(vehicle, url)` where  `vehicle.UrlID ! = url` will make it past the filter., whereas what you really want to do is to prevent a vehicle from being included if **any** url in the list matches its `UrlId`.
Not only will your query return the vehicles that should be filtered out, but each vehicle will be repeated multiple times.

I suggest:

```
var urlIds = new HashSet<string>(ListDetailUrls);
var missingVehicles = unsoldVehicles.Where(vehicle => !urlIds.Contains(vehicle.UrlID))
                                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need all the items from the `unsoldVehicles` list with `UrlIDs` that don't appear in the `ListDetailUrls` list:

```
var missingVehicles = unsoldVehicles.Where(uv => !ListDetailUrls.Contains(uv.UrlID)).ToList();
```