# Using LINQ Except() with two collections of different types

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I can't use the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830263/difference-of-two-list-with-different-types-using-linq) because it's specific to the structure the asker was using.

Currently, I'm going:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns)
    if( !props.Any(p => p.Name == dataColumn.ColumnName) )
        ...
```

I'd much rather have something in one line, such as:

```
foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>.Except(props) )
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var columns = dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(column => !props.Any(p => p.Name == column.ColumnName);
foreach(DataColumn in columns) 
    ....
```

Or the slightly optimized version (as always, depending on the runtime number of columns, properties, etc, etc):

```
PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetProperties();
var lookup = new HashSet<string>(props.Select(x=>x.Name));
var columns = dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(column => !lookup.Contains(column.Name));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, dataAsDataRow.Table.Columns is a DataColumnCollection, not an array of DataColumns, so this give a compiler error: "'DataColumnCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where'". This, however, is easily fixed by adding "Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where". Thanks you for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert one to the other using a projection (i.e. `Select`), or some logic that can evaluate to a boolean then use a `Where`.